# Not getting array value in form submit method using mysqli_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, arrays, submit

submit page

```
<form  id='frmFeePayment' action="payment-obj.php" method="post">    
<input type='hidden' name='hdnStudentDbKey[]' id='hdnStudentDbKey' value='$StudentDbKey'/>
<input type='hidden' name='hdnFeeAmountDbKey[]' id='hdnFeeAmountDbKey' value='$FeeAmountDbKey'/>
<input type='hidden' name='hdnFeeNameDbKey[]' id='hdnFeeNameDbKey' value='$FeeNameDbKey'/>  

</form>
```

in my data receive page. payment-obj.php

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "TestDB");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$StudentDbKey = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['hdnStudentDbKey']);
$FeeAmountDbKey = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['hdnFeeAmountDbKey']);
$FeeNameDbKey = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['hdnFeeNameDbKey']);
```

I am not getting value using above code.
But If I use direct $_POST method I am getting value.

```
$StudentDbKey = $_POST['hdnStudentDbKey'];
$FeeAmountDbKey = $_POST['hdnFeeAmountDbKey'];
$FeeNameDbKey = $_POST['hdnFeeNameDbKey'];
```

Can any one tell me what is wrong with mysqli_real_escape_string()

Thanks

Comment: Because `hdnStudentDbKey` is __array__ (as two other fields). And if you already use `mysqli` - __forget__ about `escape_string` and use __prepared statements__.

Comment: @u_mulder If I remove escape_string then how I will handle escape sequence character if somebody entered

Comment: With using __prepared statements__.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP uses the square bracket syntax to convert form inputs into an array, so when you use `name="hdnStudentDbKey[]"` in your html form you will get an array.

when you do this:

```
$StudentDbKey = $_POST['hdnStudentDbKey']; // Returns an array
print_r($StudentDbKey); // Shows you all the values in the array
```

But for the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function you have to insert the string value. Not the array value.

So you can do like this:

```
$StudentDbKey = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['hdnStudentDbKey'][0]); 
$FeeAmountDbKey = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['hdnFeeAmountDbKey'][0]); 
$FeeNameDbKey = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['hdnFeeNameDbKey'][0]);
```

Or `mysql_real_escape_string` the whole array, the easy way:

```
$_POST['hdnStudentDbKey'] = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $_POST['hdnStudentDbKey']);
$_POST['hdnFeeAmountDbKey'] = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $_POST['hdnFeeAmountDbKey']);
$_POST['hdnFeeNameDbKey'] = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $_POST['hdnFeeNameDbKey']);
```

Comment: Kulatunga Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the values as below

```
$StudentDbKey = $_POST['hdnStudentDbKey'][0];
$FeeAmountDbKey = $_POST['hdnFeeAmountDbKey'][0];
$FeeNameDbKey = $_POST['hdnFeeNameDbKey'][0];
```

This kind of arrays will be useful to have the same name for input types.

Just try to print the $_POST array and you will get it

Comment: I am trying like this  `$StudentDbKey = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['hdnStudentDbKey']); echo $StudentDbkey[0]` what is wrong in this?

Comment: As Nadun Kulatunge said `mysqli_real_escape_string` should have two parameters. once is connection string and another one is string